# mouseClicked event in a case where a JLabel is placed on top of another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jlabel, mouseclick-event

I have a JLabel (say label1) on my JFrame at certain coordinates, then I have another JLabel (say label2) that is placed exactly on top of label1 (i.e. it has exactly the same origin and size as label1).

I have registered both these labels to receive mouseClicked event.

```
label1 = new JLabel();
label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
label1.setName("label1");
label1.addMouseListener(this);
contentPane.add(label1);
label1.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);

label2 = new JLabel();
label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
label2.setName("label2");
label2.addMouseListener(this);
contentPane.add(label2);
label2.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

But when I click on the label, only label1 gets notified (which was added before label2).

I am looking for a solution so that both my label objects get notified.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Answer (score 3):

> But when I click on the label, only label1 gets notified (which was added before label2).

Swing paints components in the reverse order that they were added to the panel. So label 2 gets painted before label 1. This explains why label 1 gets the event.

> I am looking for a solution so that both my label objects get notified.

Add the MouseListner to the panel. Then you will need to loop through all the components on the panel to see if the component contains the mouse point. When you find a match you do your processing.

There is probably a better solution. Why do you need this? Why are you using a null layout.

Comment: i don't understand if he clicks in one label, why the other label should get notified?

Comment: @nachokk, I agree, it sounds like a bad design, which is why I asked for clarification of the requirement.

Comment: +1 for *Swing paints components in the reverse order that they were added to the panel*..

Comment: Thanks your explanation helped. Actually building a game in which each player's token is an image and hence placed in a JLabel.
Also a player's token can kill opponent's token, meanwhile I check for the valid kill, I want to store opponent's token in one JLabel where as player1's token in other JLabel.

Essentially one hiding the other.

Comment: When you kill the other players token you should remove the label so you don't have two labels at the same position.

Comment: Thanks! Will consider. BTW I am new to swing (and UI programming), can you suggest me any tutorials/books which will teach me how to effectively use Swing components and refrain from making bad design choices?

Comment: The [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) explains the basics of using Swing. Understanding some of the basic concepts will help with design.